# How to detect errors from GraphServiceClient SendMail

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the following code to send email for the logged in user.

```
                await _graphClient.Me.SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Initially it was executing be no email was sent.  After poking around I figured out that a permission was not set.  Unfortunately the try..catch around it was not tripped.  My questions is if there is a way of detecting that an error occurred with this call.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> Unfortunately the try..catch around it was not tripped.

`PostAsync()` method should throw a [`ServiceException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.serviceexception?view=graph-core-dotnet) on error. 
For example, in case of missing permissions:

```
try
{
     await graphClient.Users[userId].SendMail(message).Request().PostAsync();
} 
catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
}
```

the following error should be printed:

```
Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```